# C++ | Method scope pointer management

Tags: c++, pointers

I got a question about pointers:

```
class CAppFramework : public IBaseApp
{
public:
    CAppFramework( std::initializer_list< CClientApp* > input );
    CAppFramework( );
    ~CAppFramework( );

    void Create( ) override;
    void Release( ) override;

    template< class T > T** Request( std::string c_appname )
    {
        for ( auto c_app : m_ClientApps )
        {
            if ( c_app -> GetName( ) == c_appname )
            {
                T** t_app = reinterpret_cast< T** >( c_app );

                return t_app;
            }
       }

       return nullptr;
   }

   std::vector< CClientApp* >& GetClientApps( );

private:
   std::vector< CClientApp* > m_ClientApps;
};


void CTest::Create( )
{
    std::cout << "Ayye" << std::endl;

    CTest* test = *( m_Framework->Request< CTest >( 
    "Test" ) );
    test -> RunTest( );
}
```

CTest is a derived class from CClientApp.

Do I need to delete test? Cause if I do, I get an access violation.
I suppose that is because "Request" is returning a pointer to a pointer that is inside a vector, so when I dereference it and delete it, it would delete the object in the vector which will / might still get used?

This is more of a general question. Do I need to delete every pointer or just pointers that are dynamically allocated using "new"?

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: if you need `reinterpret_cast` something is badly wrong in this case.  Can you provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: Sorry, I edited and tried to make it understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously don't need to delete every pointer, otherwise you would have to write code like this:

```
 int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
      // stuff
      delete argv;
 }
```

If you explicitly create something with `new` and assign the pointer new gives you to a raw pointer, then you need to `delete` that pointer. Of course, this is error prone, and can't be made exception-safe, and so you should be using things like std::unique_ptr and std::make_unique instead.

Comment: So that means my function CTest::Create is not causing any memory leaks?

Comment: Not obviously, but then it's not at all obvious what it _is_ doing or why it is doing it. If you have to ask questions like this, I don't really think you are in a good position to design an application framework.